# Doing miswak and coronavirus

Tags: practical-islam, taharah

Can I do miswak five times before every prayer nowadays. Because they're saying not to touch anything or bring it your mouth and other organs.

Comment: If that's the case how you do wudu'? You should handle it like with a teeth brush after being seek change it.

Comment: Brushing teeth is sunnah\mustahab not obligatory. Either way it is possible to practice caution without giving it up entirely: Wash your hands beforehand with soap and do not touch the bristles of the siwak. Keep the siwak covered\at home and if you suspect contamination then you can use a new one or also disinfect it with Hydrogen Peroxide.

Comment: I think questions like these should be asked where there is medical expertise involved. Since this is not a fatwa site..

Comment: @Kilise yes this is not a fatwa site, but OP should elaborate first. He basically asks about how to use miswak while his statement says you can't do wudu' in first place. This way the whole question doesn't make sense. And I don't know of any expert who would agree to this claim. As long as you have washed your hands etc. everythng should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Prophet recommendation to do miswak with Wudu! So you would wash the miswak first and rinse your mouth afterwards. According to all Muslim doctors I have heard recently, coronavirus  washes away with water inshaAllah!